# Rails: How do I run a before_save only if certain conditions are met?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a before_save method that I call that renames an uploaded image.

```
before_save :randomize_file_name

def randomize_file_name
  extension = File.extname(screen_file_name).downcase
  key = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(8)
  self.screen.instance_write(:file_name, "#{key}#{extension}")
end
```

That method is part of my `Item` model.

That works great when I create a new item or need to update the image associated with an item...but the problem is that if I need to update an item but NOT the image, the `randomize_file_name` method still gets run and renames the file in the database (though not the file itself, obviously).

So, I'm thinking I need to figure out a way to only run `randomize_file_name` if a file is included in the form submission...but I'm not sure how to pull that off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [dirty objects](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/3/31/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-dirty-objects).

```
before_save :randomize_file_name

def randomize_file_name
  # assuming the field that holds the name
  # is called screen_file_name
  if screen_file_name_changed?
    extension = File.extname(screen_file_name).downcase
    key = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(8)
    self.screen.instance_write(:file_name, "#{key}#{extension}")
  end
end
```

Comment: This won't get it either. What if the user uploads a new file with the same file name? In this case the file_name will be the same but you may want a different key.

Answer (score 4):

```
before_save :randomize_file_name

def randomize_file_name
  if screen_file_name
    extension = File.extname(screen_file_name).downcase
    key = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(8)
    return self.screen.instance_write(:file_name, "#{key}#{extension}") unless !screen_changed?
  end
end
```

This checks only if the file has changed. Works 90% of the time

Answer (score 1):

go ahead and make your before_save method called on every save but as a first step inside the method you are now having called "before save" you should have an  if condition that tests for the specific case you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a quick check at the top of the function and return if you don't need to do anything.

```
def randomize_file_name
  return unless screen_file_name # or whatever check you need to do
  extension = File.extname(screen_file_name).downcase
  key = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(8)
  self.screen.instance_write(:file_name, "#{key}#{extension}")
end
```

**Edit after comment:**

You can use the dirty object as mentioned by Simone Carletti, or you can get creative.

In the Model:

```
attr_accessor :some_random_field_name_for_you_to_rename

def randomize_file_name
  return unless some_random_field_name_for_you_to_rename
  extension = File.extname(screen_file_name).downcase
  key = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(8)
  self.screen.instance_write(:file_name, "#{key}#{extension}")
end
```

In the form:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :some_random_field_name_for_you_to_rename, :value => "1" %>
```

Comment: But the problem is that if the form doesn't contain an upload, then it just pulls "screen_file_name" from the database for that ID...I need to specifically check if the form submission includes anything for the image field...and I don't know how to do that from the model.